# Is it possible to get an object by its primary key in django-nonrel / Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm trying to retrieve a model object like the code below:

```
(r'^album/(?P<album_id>\w+)/$', 'core.views.album'),

def album(request, album_id):
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
```

The problem is that the PK is not an integer:

```
>>> a = Album.objects.all()[0]
>>> a.pk
46L
```

The error I'm getting when I run the view:

```
ValueError at /album/46L/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '46L'
```

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was unrelated with the urls / views. Everytime I executed "runserver" my local datastore was being erased. So the data I was able to retrieve when using "shell" was not synced correctly.

This happened because, for some weird reason, I commented this line (and forgot about it) on settings.py:

```
AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'
```

Answer (score 1):

`46L` is a long integer, not a string, so you should treat it as a number and not a word in urls.py:

```
(r'^album/(?P<album_id>\d+)/$', 'core.views.album'),
```

then the url `/album/46/` will end up calling:

```
def album(request, album_id):
    #album = Album.objects.get(pk=46L)
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
```

Or if you need to keep the 'L' in the url for some reason, cast it as a long before using it:

```
album = Album.objects.get(pk=long(album_id))
```

Comment: That was my first try, the error for http://localhost:8081/album/46/ is: DoesNotExist at /album/46/ -- Album matching query does not exist.

Comment: Tried to cast as long with no success. :(

Comment: Can't you convert to int() instead? album = Album.objects.get(pk=int(album_id)). This would work until you long integer values got too big, but is that a constraint in your example?

Comment: You might want to update your question with your current code